# ngnix config setting for url specific redirect

Tags: nginx

I want to redirect a specific URL to a local server running on a different port, not sure what I need to add in nginx.config.  thanks!

```
e.g:  for url /v1/jobs
I want to direct it to a local server running on port 9090
```

below is my current nginx config settings:

```
http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;    

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [proxy pass](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass)

```
  location ^~ /v1/jobs {
    proxy_pass http://www.domain.com:9090
  }
```

the URI is kept intact - you may use a *rewrite* before *proxy-pass* to change the URI if necessary.

To restart *nginx*

- either do `nginx -s reload`
- or send HUP to the process `killall -HUP nginx`
- or restart service `service nginx restart`
- or `/etc/init.d/nginx restart`